# Unstable bash statement

Tags: bash, scripting

I have the code in my bash scripts that works unstable:

```
# check every line of check_list file presents in my_prog output
MY_LIST=`./my_prog`
for l in $(cat check_list); do
    if ! echo -n "$MY_LIST" | grep -q -x "$l"; then
        die "Bad line: '$l'"
    fi
done
```

This piece of code of my huge scripting pool shows "Bad line: 'smthng'" with probability around 1/5000. I wasn't able to represent this event by the naked script but only in my huge scripting pool.

However this code seems to work very fine:

```
# check every line of check_list file presents in my_prog output
./my_prog > my_list
for l in $(cat check_list); do
    if ! grep -q -x "$l" "my_list"; then
        die "Bad line: '$l'"
    fi
done
```

The reason why I don't like the second statement is that its use an intermediate file "my_list".
What could be a problem of unstable working of the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling grep for every line in your check_list, you can run one awk program:

```
awk '
  FILENAME == ARGV[1] {check_list[$0]; next}
  $0 in check_list {
     print "bad line: " $0
     exit 1
  }
' check_list <(./my_prog)
```

Or, see if there are any common lines between your program's output and your check_list:

```
common=$( comm -12 <(sort -u check_list) <(./my_prog | sort -u) )
if [ -n "$common" ]; then
    echo "bad lines: "
    echo "$common"
    die
fi
```

Comment: comm works perfect, thanks! One remark for my case I use "comm -23"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with the first version but you can easily eliminate the creation of a temporary file.
Note the you'll have to correct the logic, i did not really understand that, probably you'll want to update a variable in the inner loop and decide whether to die after the inner loop.

```
for i in $*; do
  for l in $(cat check_list); do
    if ! echo "$i" | grep -q -x "$l"; then
        die "Bad line: '$i', '$l'"
    fi
  done  
done | ./my_prog
```